# Cypher & Neo4J Beers database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to solve a question with Cypher in Neo4J where I need to find the `BEER_STYLE` that has the best combination of smell and looks. The relations are as follows:

```
(:REVIEW)<-[:REVIEWED]-(:BEER)-[:HAS_STYLE]->(:BEER_STYLE)
```

One beer sometimes has more than one review and the Reviews nodes have the two properties of interest: look and smell. Sometimes these 2 can be `NaN` and I have to find the style that has the best combination of those 2 (which I thought it could be the average of averages).

I tried to code a general idea and asked ChatGPT to polish until it works, but I'm not very confident and wanted to ask here.
This is the code I got, can someone help/correct me to improve it?

```cypher
MATCH (s:STYLE)<-[h:HAS_STYLE]-(b:BEERS)-[rev:REVIEWED]->(r:REVIEWS)
WITH s, 
     CASE WHEN r.look <> 'NaN' THEN toFloat(r.look) ELSE null END AS look,
     CASE WHEN r.smell <> 'NaN' THEN toFloat(r.smell) ELSE null END AS smell
WITH s, AVG(look) AS avg_look, AVG(smell) AS avg_smell
WITH s, avg_look, avg_smell, ((avg_look + avg_smell) / 2) AS total
RETURN s AS STYLE, MAX(total) AS Final_Class
ORDER BY Final_Class DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Preprocess to convert strings to floats

Assuming that the `look` and `smell` values do not need to be stored as strings, you should first change them to floats to avoid having to do conversions every time you use those properties:

```
MATCH (r:REVIEWS)
SET r.look = CASE WHEN r.look <> 'NaN' THEN toFloat(r.look) END
SET r.smell = CASE WHEN r.smell <> 'NaN' THEN toFloat(r.smell) END
```

Notes:

- `NULL` is the default value for `CASE`, so it does not need to be specified in an `ELSE`.
- When you assign `NULL` to a property, the property is removed.
- You should also change the code that imports your data to follow suit.

##### Simplified query

After the above one-time change, your use case can be simplified to:

```
MATCH (s:STYLE)<-[:HAS_STYLE]-(:BEERS)-[:REVIEWED]->(r:REVIEWS)
RETURN s AS STYLE, ((AVG(r.look) + AVG(r.smell)) / 2) AS Final_Class
ORDER BY Final_Class DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Notes:

- Your original query did not need to call the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/) `MAX` on the `total` value for each `s`, since there would only be a single `total` per `s`. This is because the aggregating function `AVG` in the following clause would create only a single `avg_look` and `avg_smell` per `s`:

  ```
  WITH s, AVG(look) AS avg_look, AVG(smell) AS avg_smell
  ```